# pdo - prepared statement loses data?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a query (PHP, Mysql) a table named 'table' that looks like this:

```
 id | name
-------------
  6 | abc
  10| xxx
  52| def
```

And a query:

```
$ids = '5,62'

$name = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE id IN ( :ids )');
$name -> bindValue(':ids', $ids, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$name -> execute();
$name = $name->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($nazwa);
```

I would expect to get a result like

```
 id | name
-------------
  6 | abc
  52| def
```

Unofrtunately i get only:

```
 id | name
-------------
  6 | abc
```

As if second value would be ignored. If I change the query to:

```
$name = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE id IN (' $ids ')');
```

It all goes right. Can you tell me why prepared statement doesnt take under consideration imploded table with commas?

Comment: Two parameters ain't one parameter; `bindValue` is one parameter. If that value contains values for two parameters, you're using the wrong tool. And yes, this has been asked before. `IN ()` plus prepared statements, e.g. here an example for a variable number of parameters and PDO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7128193/367456

Comment: i have read link you provided but it still doesnt make me on my way to solve problem. For me "bind" is variable that i put to earlier made query. And I this case string '6, 52' is just another string that is placed between ( and ) in mysql query. I dont see that it is two, three and more parameters.. Dont know why should i treat it on this level as 2 or more. Sorry for that - i'm new to pdo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the comment field does not allow to write that well, here an answer that is merely a comment:

Let's say you have two IDs:

```
$name = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE id IN ( :id1, :id2 )');
```

Let's say you have three IDs:

```
$name = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE id IN ( :id1, :id2, :id3 )');
```

You see the pattern? You have as many values as you have IDs. Formulate the prepare statement as well as perform the bind statements accordingly to the number of IDs you have.

So the answer is: You need to change your code so that it actually reflects the number of IDs you want to handle. The MySQL server will not magically interpret a comma-separated list inside a string as multiple IDs. Instead you need to tell the server about each single ID.

Comment: yes, it's now much more clear :) thank you. Still I have to find out how to map proper ammount of ids because sometimes they might be 2 ids and another time - 25. But i guess the easiest way is to put bindValue into foreach loop. Thank you once more.

Comment: Yes, `array`s are your friends for a variable amount of IDs. Looping, `implode` and such. Also there are named and positional parameters with PDO. Take a look what suits best for your needs.